# insert data in mongodb with python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

this is my first shot at using dbs and I'm having some trouble with the basics. Tried to look online but couldnt find answers to simple questions. When I try to add some info to my db, I get a whole bunch of errors.

```
import pymongo


def get_db():
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    client = MongoClient("mongodb://xxxxxx:xxxxxx@ds029735.mlab.com:29735/xxxxxxx")
    db = client.myDB
    return db

def add_country(db):
    db.countries.insert({"name": "Canada"})

def get_country(db):
    return db.contries.find_one()

db = get_db()
add_country(db)
```

I got this error message:

```
File "/Users/vincentfortin/Desktop/Python_code/mongo.py", line 21, in <module>
    add_country(db)
  File "/Users/vincentfortin/Desktop/Python_code/mongo.py", line 11, in add_country
    db.countries.insert({"name": "Canada"})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2212, in insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 535, in _insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern, op_id, bypass_doc_val)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 516, in _insert_one
    check_keys=check_keys)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 239, in command
    read_concern)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 102, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(response_doc, None, allowable_errors)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 205, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: not authorized on myDB to execute command { insert: "countries", ordered: true, documents: [ { _id: ObjectId('579a6c6ed51bef1274162ff4'), name: "Canada" } ] }
```

Comment: please edit the formatting, this is horrible to read! I don't know about your problem, but maybe a write permissions problem? Can you try with a read request instead of a write request?

Comment: when I only do :
    db =get_db()
    print db

it prints this:

Database(MongoClient(host=['ds029735.mlab.com:29735'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), u'myDB'

which I guess means I am connected to db, but I can't seem to add anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check twice if your `xxxxxxx` from `ds029735.mlab.com:29735/xxxxxxx` is equal to `myDB` from `db = client.myDB`. I mean if your connection string is `mongodb://username:password@ds029735.mlab.com:29735/xyz` then your code should be `db = client.xyz` and not `db = client.zyx` (or other names).
2. Check in mLab control panel if your user is Read-Only https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIRr2.png

Both of these issues returns errors like your so I don't know with which one you have faced.

Comment: Thanks for response. Why should user be Read-Only ? will check later if they work, but I know my user isn't Read-Only.

Comment: @VincFort it shouldn't but `OperationFailure: not authorized on myDB to execute command` can be thrown if it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

#import json

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
mydb = client.db_University

def add_client(student_name, student_age, student_roll, student_branch):
    unique_client = mydb.students.find_one({"name":student_name}, {"_id":0})
    if unique_client:
        return " already exists"
    else:
        mydb.students.insert(
                {
                "name" : student_name,
                "age" : student_age,
                "roll no" : student_roll,
                "branch" : student_branch,

                })
        return "student added successfully"

student_name = raw_input("Enter stuent Name: ")
student_age = raw_input("Enter student age: ")
student_roll = raw_input("Enter student roll no: ")
student_branch = raw_input("Enter student branch: ")

print add_client(student_name,student_age,student_roll,student_branch)


def view_client(student_name):
    user = mydb.students.find_one({"name":student_name}, {"_id":0})
    if user:
        name = user["name"]
        age = user["age"]
        rollno = user["roll no"]
        branch = user["branch"]

        return {"name":name,"age":age,"roll no":rollno,"branch":branch}
    else:
        return "Sorry, No such student exists"


user = raw_input("Enter student name to find: ")
user_data = view_client(user)

print user_data
```

Comment: add a description text.